# Chaining asynchronous operations in iOS

Tags: ios, recursion, afnetworking

I am trying to fix an app that downloads records from a URL at Google, which contains 79 records. My app loads the first 70, and then unexpectedly stops.

I inherited code that has a `loadLatLong` method, which fires a `GET` request to the URL through `AFHTTPRequestOperationManager`, and then waits for a callback in the `success:` block handler.

The part that does not look right to me is this: when `success:` callback arrives, the block calls `loadLatLong` method again, which advances the counter, and sends another block with the same block. This continues until all parts are loaded. Unfortunately, the process stops early, which makes me think that there's something wrong with this way of chaining requests.

Is this way of handling a sequence of GET calls from a URL appropriate, and my error is elsewhere? Is there a better way of chaining asynchronous calls?

Here is the code:

```
- (void)loadLatLong {
    indx++;
    if (indx == [datalist count]) {
        [self showMarker];
        [self.progressbar setProgress:1.0 animated:YES];
        return;
    }
    PointClass *pt = datalist[indx];
    NSString *stPt = [pt.Location stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSString *str = [stPt stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"+"];
    NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=%@&sensor=false&key=<API KEY>", str];

    NSURL *urlString = [NSURL URLWithString:url];
    AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];

    manager.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];
    manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes setByAddingObject:@"text/html"];
    [manager GET:[urlString absoluteString ]parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        NSArray *response = [responseObject objectForKey:@"results"];
        if (response.count == 0) return;
        NSDictionary *geo = [response[0] objectForKey:@"geometry"];
        NSDictionary *location = [geo objectForKey:@"location"];

        pt.lat = [[location objectForKey:@"lat"] doubleValue];
        pt.lng = [[location objectForKey:@"lng"] doubleValue];
        datalist[indx] = pt;
        NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:@"%%d \n"], indx);

        // Calling the method that started the call again
        [self loadLatLong];
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Error");
    }];
}
```

Comment: please remove key from the code if this is your real api-key , just replace it with a placeholder , 

what is the initial indx ? it gets incremented always , is it "-1" before this method gets called ? if its 0 , then it will skip first object , can you also add NSLog to log the case when response.count == 0 and you are returning from the block ?

Comment: @ogres Thanks for responding. How should I write the NSLog you are speaking about?

Comment: @ogres Like this   `NSLog(@"%d", (int)response.count);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although the code looks recursive, the recursion is not there. The call to `[self loadLatLong]` happens in a different context, when `AFHTTPRequestOperationManager` calls the completion block asynchronously. The invocation of `loadLatLong` method that has initiated the request is off the call stack by then, so the call is not recursive.

The reason why the code stops before loading all records is this error check line:

```
if (response.count == 0) return;
```

It looks like the seventieth response comes with no data - perhaps because Google has no record for the point at `datalist[70]`. At this point the code sees `response.count` at zero, and returns without making a call to `[self loadLatLong]`.

You can fix this problem by replacing `if (response.count == 0) return;` with

```
if (response.count == 0) {
    [self loadLatLong];
    return;
}
```